# SMTP mail sending with SendGrid not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, sendmail, sendgrid

This is my simple EmailService class in IdentityConfig.cs file.

```
public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
{
    public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        // Plug in your email service here to send an email.
        // return Task.FromResult(0);
        const string userName = "ashish_qluto";
        const string from = "akanksha16296@gmail.com";
        const string password = "xxxxxx";
        //const int port = 587;

        var smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.sendgrid.net", Convert.ToInt32(587));

        smtpClient.Port = 587;
        // smtpClient.ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime = 1;
        smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

        // smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
        NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
        smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
        smtpClient.Credentials = credentials;

        var mailMessage = new MailMessage(from, message.Destination);
        mailMessage.Subject = message.Subject;
        mailMessage.Body = message.Body;

        return smtpClient.SendMailAsync(mailMessage);
    }
}
```

This is my Register method's POST version where I have tried to send the email link after successful Registration.

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            var code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
            var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
            await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking this link:");
            //ViewBag.Link = callbackUrl;
            return View("CheckYourEmail");
        }
        AddErrors(result);
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

I have seen many articles relating to mail sending. I have configured nothing in my web.config file. I have simply hard-coded everything here in these two classes.

- I am using only UserName not the gmail account name.
- I have signed up for SendGrid free account. I have properly placed username and password and email account name wherever required.
- I was testing this on my local host. I read somewhere not to deploy on local host. Try out on external server.I have deployed too.
- I have configured nothing on windows azure for free SendGrid account.
  I have wasted a whole day figuring it out and tried multiple options.
  The Error which i am getting is--

I have changed the port number from 527 to 465 as suggested on SendGrid documentation for SSL.
Now, i am getting following error---
Exception Details: System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Syntax error, command unrecognized. The server response was: 
and the line which is causing error is---

```
  var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail","Account",new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
       /// this function SendEmailAsync is causing Syntax error
        await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id,"Confirm your account","Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

        return View("CheckYourEmail");
```

and the entire stack trace is here---http://pastebin.com/yMiZaS9Q

Comment: Can you provide the entire exception message and stacktrace?

Comment: I also hope that those credentials in your code are not your actual email address and password. Even if you edit them out, they will still be visible in the edit history. You should probably delete the question.

Comment: @user1666620 He's doing it here:  var mailMessage = new MailMessage(from, message.Destination);
The first parameter is the from the second is the to

Comment: @JoaoFSA ah yeah thanks, misread that part.

Comment: @user1666620 I have pasted the entire stack trace in the link and Exception message also

Comment: The "Server response was ]" makes me suspect that the server's port 587 isn't SMTP.

Comment: @Duston So, what should i try in place of 587 for the server port ??

Comment: You can try port 25, but it also depends whether it's using TLS or not.  It's possible the port 587 you're connecting to is trying to negotiate an encrypted connection that you're not supporting.  http://blog.mailgun.com/25-465-587-what-port-should-i-use/ explains some of this.  You might also try a program called "smtp4dev" that will run a dummy SMTP daemon on your box.  It's quite handy for testing.

Answer (score 1):

```
const string userName = "ashish_qluto";
```

Needs to be..

```
const string userName = "apikey";
```

For password...

```
const string password = "xxxxxx";  // xxxxxx = sendgrid api key
```

See sendgrid smpt documentation for more details..

https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/getting-started-smtp/